# expression does not produce a value when calling a sub

Tags: vb.net, oop, methods

i want to call this public sub hungrys(gutom as string) from my zooanimal class to my form1.vb. for reference, please refer to my code. 
i always get an error "expression does not produce a value" in my Textbox10.text = za.hungrys(gutom as string)

```
Public Class ZooAnimal

Public Sub New()
hungry = isHungry()

Public Function isHungry() As Boolean
    If age > 0 Then
        hungry = True
    End If
    If age <= 0 Then
        hungry = False
    End If
    Return hungry
End Function

 Public Sub hungrys(ByRef gutom As String)
    If hungry = True Then
        gutom = "The zoo animal is hungry"
    End If
    If hungry = False Then
        gutom = "The zoo animal is not hungry "
    End If
End Sub

Public Class Form1
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

Dim za As New ZooAnimal
Dim gutom As String = ""

TextBox10.Text = za.hungrys(gutom)
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour].  The error is accurate.  `hungrys` is a sub which means it returns nothing, yet you are trying to assign a result as if you wrote it as a function...or assign that string argument to the textbox.  You should also set `Option Strict On` - `age` comes out of nowhere

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to get a value out of a `Sub` with a `ByRef` parameter rather than the return value of a `Function` then this:

```
TextBox10.Text = za.hungrys(gutom)
```

would need to be this:

```
za.hungrys(gutom)
TextBox10.Text = gutom
```

The first line calls the `Sub` and assigns a new value to the variable and the second line displays the variable's value in the `TextBox`.

Unless it's as a learning exercise though, there's no good reason to use a `ByRef` parameter there.  You'd normally write that method like this:

```
Public Function hungrys() As String
    Dim gutom As String

    If hungry Then
        gutom = "The zoo animal is hungry"
    Else
        gutom = "The zoo animal is not hungry "
    End If

    Return gutom
End Sub
```

and then call it like this:

```
Dim gutom As String = za.hungrys()

TextBox10.Text = gutom
```

or just:

```
TextBox10.Text = za.hungrys()
```

Notice that that method uses an `If...Else` rather than two separate `If` blocks.

By the way, that is a terrible, terrible name for a method.  Firstly, it should start with an upper-case letter.  Secondly, "hungrys" doesn't tell you what the method does.  If I read that with no context, I'd have little idea what it's purpose was.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `Sub` to `Function`.
`Sub` are procedures that **do not** Return a value.
`Function` do return values.
It's just that simple.

Also, declare the data type of your parameter `gutom As Boolean` because it stores a value that could be `True or False`.

Do not use redundant `If`.. Use `If-Else` instead.

```
Public Function hungrys(ByVal gutom As Boolean) As String
  If hungry = True Then
      gutom = "The zoo animal is hungry"
  Else
      gutom = "The zoo animal is not hungry "
  End If
  Return gutom
End Function
```

Call it By

```
TextBox10.Text = za.hungrys(True)
```