# Public Sub hungrys(gutom)does not return the correct output

Tags: vb.net, oop

the program should return the message "the zoo animal is hungry if the input age is greater than 0 else the zoo animal is not hungry" but when i try to run the program, the result is always "the zoo animal is hungry" even if your input is 0. Please refer to the code. but when i try to use public function the output is correct. but i cannot use public function because the requirement is to use public sub().

```
Public Class ZooAnimal
Private name As String
Private type As String
Private age As Integer
Private hungry As Boolean
Public Sub New()
    name = "Brown"
    type = ""
    age = 10
    hungry = isHungry()
End Sub
Public Sub New(ByVal name As String, ByVal type As String, ByVal age As Integer, ByVal hungry As Boolean)
    Me.name = name
    Me.type = type
    Me.age = age
    Me.hungry = isHungry()
End Sub
Public Function getName() As String
    Return name
End Function
Public Function getype() As String
    Return type
End Function
Public Function getAge() As Integer
    Return age
End Function
Public Function isHungry() As Boolean
    If age > 0 Then
        hungry = True
    Else
        hungry = False
    End If
    Return hungry
End Function
Public Sub hungrys(ByRef gutom As String)
    If hungry = True Then
        gutom = "The zoo animal is hungry"
    Else
        gutom = "The zoo animal is not hungry "
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub eat(ByRef eating As String)
    eating = "The zoo animal is eating"
End Sub
Public Sub sleep(ByRef sleeping As String)
    sleeping = "The zoo animal is sleeping"
End Sub
```

End Class

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

Dim za As ZooAnimal
Dim zaa As New ZooAnimal
Dim gutom As String = ""
Dim eating As String = ""

zaa.hungrys(gutom)
zaa.eat(eating)

za = New ZooAnimal(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text, TextBox3.Text, zaa.isHungry)
    TextBox10.Text = za.getAge & " " & gutom & " "& eating
```

Comment: Your example is incomplete and it's difficult to tell from your description exactly what you're trying to do and what was going wrong.  As it stands, the code won't compile.  But even if we guessed at what the rest of the code looked like, it still never actually calls the `hungrys` method, which seems to be the one you're having trouble with.

Comment: Please see the code again, i already edited the code, for your reference. thank you.

Comment: You added the call to the `hungrys` method (along with some other unnecessary methods that never get called), but my original point still stands.  It doesn't compile and you haven't explained clearly what it's doing wrong, what else you tried and how that went wrong, and what it is that you need it to do. For instance, you never set the age or the hungry boolean, so it's not clear why however you're setting it isn't working.  I'm not trying to be difficult.  I'd be happy to help.  It's just that at this point I honestly have no idea which part of it you don't understand.

Comment: you need to put your values into the properties first, you cant just give it the textbox3.text

Comment: the code works fine, but i do not get the right answer from the public sub hungrys(). in the public function ishungry() it says, if the age is greater than 0 then the result will be "the zoo animal is hungry". but when i input 0 still the outpt is the same.

Comment: How is this different from [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46437629/expression-does-not-produce-a-value-when-calling-a-sub)?

Comment: why are you passing hundry as a parameter. you don't use it. Public Sub New(ByVal name As String, ByVal type As String, ByVal age As Integer, ByVal hungry As Boolean)

Comment: at the previous question, it does not have argument llist/parameter in the constructor,. im sorry but im not that good in vb.net

Comment: But this question isn't about the constructor.  If it is, I've completely missed what you're asking.

Comment: After you read [ask] and take the [tour], you should study [Creating Classes in Visual Basic .NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973814.aspx)  Your class is ignoring the hungry param passed in the ctor (which is just as well since you are passing the hungry state from Animal A to Animal B).

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues with your code to be honest - I would suggest rewriting it using properties rather than functions. You can also include code in properties to produce the results you want. When you are getting the state of the animal's hunger, rather than keep track of an actual variable, just use a property that returns the information base on age.

Public Class Form1

```
Private Sub Go()
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Go()
End Sub

Public Class ZooAnimal
    Private _name As String
    Private _type As String
    Private _age As Integer
    Private _eating As Boolean
    Private _sleeping As Boolean

    Public Sub New()
        _name = "Brown"
        _type = ""
        _age = 10
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal name As String, ByVal type As String, ByVal age As Integer)
        _name = name
        _type = type
        _age = age
    End Sub

    Public Property Name As String
        Get
            Return _name
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _name = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Type As String
        Get
            Return _type
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _type = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Age As Integer
        Get
            Return _age
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            _age = value
        End Set
    End Property


    Public ReadOnly Property Hungrys() As String
        Get
            If Age > 0 Then
                Return "The zoo animal is hungry"
            Else
                Return "The zoo animal is not hungry "
            End If
        End Get
    End Property

    Public WriteOnly Property IsEating As Boolean
        Set(value As Boolean)
            _eating = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property Eating As String
        Get
            If _eating Then
                Return "The zoo animal is eating"
            Else
                Return "The zoo animal is not eating"
            End If
        End Get
    End Property

    Public WriteOnly Property IsSleeping As Boolean
        Set(value As Boolean)
            _sleeping = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property Sleeping As String
        Get
            If _sleeping Then
                Return "The zoo animal is sleeping"
            Else
                Return "The zoo animal is not sleeping"
            End If
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

Your button click event now looks like this - incidentally, when you're using Visual Studio, you should really change a thing called `Option Strict` to `On` - have a look [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/311329/option-explicit-and-option-strict-in-visual-basic--net-and-in-visual-b) to explain why

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim za As ZooAnimal
    za = New ZooAnimal(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text, CInt(TextBox3.Text))
    TextBox10.Text = za.Age & " " & za.Eating
End Sub
```